# Superset - psql Readonly user

Tags: kubernetes, psql

I am trying to configure superset in k8s. I want to add a user in psql DB where the user should not be able to DROP, TRUNCATE or any security risk access.

I Tried creating a User with only SELECT Privileges to the superset DB and later added CREATE and UPDATE privileges.
I am getting error logs as (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for sequence dbs_id_seq
after adding permission for that table again one more new table is asking for permission though the User has all Privileges.

[image]

Can anyone help me to create a User in Psql with Read only access for superset.

Comment: you need to grant `USAGE` as well as `SELECT`

Comment: I had given SELECT and USAGE to the schema. yet issue persists